# padding on parent turn margin of the child into height expandation

Tags: html, css

There is a block:

```
<div class="block">
    <p>this is a paragraph this is a paragraph</p>
</div>
```

And its style:

```
.block{background:gray; width:300px}
p{margin-top:50px}
```

This is the result:

[image: without padding on parent]

Well, but when I add `padding-top` to the .block, the result differs:

```
.block{background: gray; width:300px; padding-top:1px}
p{margin-top:50px;}
```

The result:

[image: by adding padding to parent]

It looks that by adding padding to the parent, the margin of the child (p) caused expanding.

You could checkout the fiddles: http://jsfiddle.net/YFU2f/2/ and http://jsfiddle.net/YFU2f/3/

Comment: But, what is the question? Why does it happen?

Answer (score 1):

By default, adjacent margins collapse, when you introduce a padding between them they aren't anymore adjacent, so they become separate.

In your example, the top margin you defined on the `p` element collapses with the top margin of the `body` element (which is usually 8px by default), so at the end, the distance between the top of the canvas and the top of the content box of `p` is 50px. If you introduce the padding, it becomes 8px+1px+50px=59px. You can also notice the collapse of the margin by looking at the background of the `div`: when the margin collapses, it is as if the 50px margin was only declared for the `body`.

You can find all the details in the specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: But why it happens? Why when there is no padding, the margin of body collapse?

Comment: @FarzadBayan By definition, look at the specs: the two margins here meets all the requirements defined to be _adjoining_. If you introduce the padding, this invalidates the second requirement: _no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them_. Is it more clear?

Comment: Well, but add magin=0 to body and now we have just one margin in the work. Ok, now why the padding sends the box up?

Comment: @FarzadBayan Do you mean this: jsfiddle.net/YFU2f/7 and jsfiddle.net/YFU2f/6? The box is correctly moving vertically by 1px, the background extends when there is the padding because even if a margin has no height, it can still collapse (and here it does). You can also prevent the collapse by specifying `overflow: hidden` on the `div` (jsfiddle.net/YFU2f/8).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use display p as block

```
p{margin-top:50px;display:inline-block;}
```